# ¿Comparar datos antes o después de insertar en la base de datos y cómo lograrlo?

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Tengo una duda, actualmente estoy haciendo una aplicación que usa geolocalización, se trata de generar reportes mandando la ubicación pero un problema sería como evitar los reportes duplicados o que estén muy cerca dando a pensar que es el mismo. Para esto ya existe un algoritmo que te dice que tan cerca están unas coordenadas de las otras pero mi pregunta es, ¿esto lo hago antes de insertar a la base de datos o después? Lo digo porque la base de datos de esta aplicación va a crecer en cuanto al tema de reportes, creo que al menos se llegarán a 10,000 registros y no quiero que, por ejemplo ya haya 6,000, se envíe el reporte y se quede colgado hasta que acabe la comparación con todos los registros para ver si no es duplicado, pero no sé si se puede lograr hacerlo después, no conozco bien si existan procesos en las bases de datos para esto o PHP pueda lograrlo, ¿alguien sabe si se puede hacer esto?

Comment: ¿Los reportes duplicados que hablas no tienen en cuenta la fecha u otro campo?  por otro lado 10000 registros no es un volumen inmanejable a menos que te refieras a 10000 registros a la hora ¿podrías ampliar la información?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo ideal sería que este proceso que comentas se hiciese en segundo plano antes de insertar en la base de datos. Podrías utilizar la función `shell_exec`, que tiene la funcionalidad de llamar a un script en PHP. Si ejecutas un programa con esta función, la salida deberá ser redirigida a un archivo para que pueda ejecutarse en segundo plano, si no lo haces así, PHP esperará hasta que acabe dicho script.

Un ejemplo sería:

```
$str = shell_exec("php procesar_antes_de_guardar.php > mi_archivo.txt");
```

En dicho script podrás realizar el procesamiento necesario y posteriormente guardar en la base de datos, sin necesidad de hacer esperar al usuario.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

si tu preocupacion es la cantidad de registros que vas guardando, te recomiendo que insertes solo los registros que vas a mostrar en los reportes.
Esto lo podes hacer poniendo un PK en la tabla, asi con eso controlas que ya no exista un registro identico. El PK lo podes hacer con varias columnas, como por ejemplo podrías colocar PK(Objeto, Fecha, GeoLocalizacion), estos datos nunca pueden ser null por ser PK.